# Facebook Xamarin Android app getting Content Not Found error

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin.android, facebook-app-settings

I'm having an issue with my Xamarin Android app returning the info below. From what I can tell I have everything configured correctly in the settings. The package name, class name and hash keys all look good.

Could there be something I'm missing?

I also posted in the Facebook Developer Community page but haven't received any responses.

[image: Error being displayed after click the app button on Facebook]

**Update**
Should the Class Name be MainActivity? Something like namespace.MainActivity MyCompany.Android.MainActivity

Comment: It seems you are receiving comes from the Facebook system, try to strip the URL back to just after the word "set", and takes you to the particular post.

Comment: It looks like it's an issue with Facebook itself. I removed the entire piece by piece and the message never changed. Next I removed the entire Android configuration for the app and still got the same message.

Comment: You could refer to : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/GSqREs7ZUM8/ucTFDExSWQYJ